# Are there any ways to create a wicket project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wicket

I have read the Wicket quickstart in this link: http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html
But i wonder, is it possible to make a wicket project completely by eclipse (and it's plug-in, of course), without using maven command line.

I know that Eclipse has Maven integrated plug in, could it do the magic and build a wicket project directly in Eclipse ? so I don't have to install maven in my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicket is a pure Java library. You can create a dynamic web project (if you have the appropriate Eclipse bundle or plugins), add the library file to the library folder, add it to the build path, setup the servlet context, create the basic configuration and application classes, and run it via the Eclipse internal run capabilities without using Maven. There is no dependency on the build/project tool.

But I wonder if this is a real problem, especially as Eclipse (most bundles) ship with Maven. And there is no need to use the command line at all. Just create a new Maven project and select the archetype. In the project context menu you find most relevant Maven commands as ready made run configurations or you can easily build your own, e.g. for Jetty. It is *far* easier to use Maven - especially if you are exploring. The things you want to learn probably aren't project setup specific but Wicket and solution oriented ones.

Answer (score 1):

1) Most distributions of Eclipse do NOT include maven as far as I am aware.
2) I've never seen the value in Maven and have, fortunately, been able to avoid using it.  Too complicated, too unreliable (must depend on repository being up to date), and doesn't offer much above ANT (for my tastes), and I like to know which version of libraries (JARS) are going into my builds without the build system changing/updating them behind my back.
3) Unfortunately the Maven folks are relentless in pushing into all projects.